# rvm ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 can't start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using `rvm use 1.9.2` then when trying to run `rails s` I'm getting the following error.

```
/Users/pel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/railtie.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `debug_rjs=' for ActionView::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check your `config/environments/development.rb` file, you probably have this line:

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs = true
```

Remove it. Probably best to search your entire project for any `debug_rjs` references and remove them all.

Answer (score 4):

That method is used to wrap RJS responses in a try/catch block. It was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d8f23ca627df85b33fe8db87db5483c10b62bfe6) to the Rails source. And it seems as if you are now getting an error from action_view when it trys to set the configuration from the application with [this method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/railtie.rb#L31).

Check your application configuration and remove any line that looks like this:

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs = true
```

It should be in your development config at `config/environments/development.rb`